# find first 1500 natural numbers whose factors are either ONLY 2, 3, or 5

Tags: c#

I have tried:

```
static void primeFactors(int n)
        {
            int t = 0;
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();

            for (int c = 2; c <= n; c = c + 1)
            {
                t = c;
                if (t % 2 == 0 || t % 3 == 0 || t % 5 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} : ", t);
                    while (t % 2 == 0)
                    {
                            Console.Write("{0} ", 2);
                        t = t / 2;
                    }


                    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(t); i = i + 2)
                    {
                        while (t % i == 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                            t = t / i;
                        }
                    }

                    if (t >2)
                        Console.Write("{0}", t);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

My Output:

```
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 2 2
5 : 5
6 : 2 3
8 : 2 2 2
9 : 3 3
10 : 2 5
12 : 2 2 3
14 : 2 7 ** should not be list 
15 : 3 5
16 : 2 2 2 2
18 : 2 3 3
20 : 2 2 5
21 : 3 7  ** should not be list 
22 : 2 11  ** should not be list 
24 : 2 2 2 3
25 : 5 5
26 : 2 13  ** should not be list 
27 : 3 3 3
28 : 2 2 7  ** should not be list 
30 : 2 3 5
```

Required Output :
the first 20 numbers are (factors listed after semicolon):

```
2 : 2

3 : 3

4 : 2 2 

5 : 5

6 : 2 3

8 : 2 2 2 

9 : 3 3 

10 : 2 5

12 : 2 2 3

15 : 3 5

16 : 2 2 2 2 

18 : 2 3 3 

20 : 2 2 5

24 : 2 2 2 3

25 : 5 5 

27 : 3 3 3 

30 : 2 3 5

32 : 2 2 2 2 2 

36 : 2 2 3 3 

40 : 2 2 2 5
```

Note: `14(2*7),21 (3*7), 22 (2*11), 26 (2*13)` are numbers that should not be in the list. factors must be either 2, 3 or 5 only

Comment: all are different languages, first decide which language do you want the code in?

Comment: I need in either vb /c#

Comment: Natural numbers that ONLY have 2, 3, 5 as factors... are the multiples of the three with one of the others or itself...... Change tag to those languages please.

Comment: So select EXACTLY ONE of those two languages, and delete the remaining tag spam.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about the problem is to say take the number `x` and pass it through filters (you actually began doing this in your code). The first filter would say "while the number is divisible by 2 keep dividing it by 2". The second filter would say the same thing for 3 and the third would say the same thing for 5. At the end you check to see if what you have left is equal to 1. If it is, it had no more factors. Here's some pseudo code to help out:

```
function isDivisible(t) {
    while (t % 2 == 0) {
        t = t / 2;
    }
    while (t % 3 == 0) {
        t = t / 3;
    }
    while (t % 5 == 0) {
        t = t / 5;
    }
    return t == 1;
}
```

It's probably worth noting that this is by no means the fastest way to approach this problem; there are much faster solutions.

Comment: <pre>
static void isDivisible(int t)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int num = t;
            while (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                num = num / 2;
                Console.Write(num);
            }

            while (num % 3 == 0)
            {
                num = num / 3;
                Console.Write(num);
            }

            while (num % 5 == 0)
            {
                num = num / 5;
                Console.Write(num);
            }

            if (num == 1)
                return ;

        }
Output: 
for 6 : output is 3,1, actually 2,3 
</pre>

Comment: that code is different from my function. Take a look at my code again (I tested it, it works). My function returns a boolean indicating whether or not a number is exclusively divisible by 2, 3, and 5